# modify class for divs in jquery mobile grid when items are added using knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, knockout.js

I want to create a 3x3 grid with images loaded using knockout binding

```
<fieldset class="ui-grid-b" data-bind="foreach: Icons">
 <div>
    <img alt="" src="../res/placeholder.png" style="width: 80px; height: 80px" />
 </div>
</fieldset>
```

The Images property is from the view model and it is loaded asynchronously by a ajax call.

I need to set the div for each image like this:

for 1st div: `<div class="ui-block-a" />`
for 2nd div:`<div class="ui-block-b" />`
for 3rd div:`<div class="ui-block-c" />`
for 4th div:`<div class="ui-block-a" />`
for 5th div:`<div class="ui-block-b" />`
for 6th div:`<div class="ui-block-c" />`
...

so the class name is "ui-block-" + div_index % 3

the problem is I do not know how to set the class name.
i tried using a computed observable but i cannot get the actual object(the icon model) in order to be able to return an Icons.IndexOf(icon) % 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Knockout 2.1 inside a `foreach` you have access to the `$index` variable.

```
<div data-bind="attr: {'class': $root.indexLetter($index())}">
```

Create a method in your ViewModel like this:

```
viewModel.indexLetter = function(index) {
    var abc = 'abc';
    return 'ui-block-' + abc.charAt(index % 3);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I still don't know how to make it return "a" or "b" or "c". I tried this: "<div data-bind="attr: {'class': 'ui-block-' + $parent.GetIconClass($index() % 3)}">" but it says 'Unable to parse bindings.
Message: Error: Cannot write a value to a ko.computed unless you specify a 'write' option. If you wish to read the current value, don't pass any parameters.;

Comment: Take a look at my code, indexLetter is just a plain JavaScript function.  It's not a computed.

Comment: Here is a very simple JSFiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/jearles/RhmTb/

Comment: wow, I was pretty tired I think, not sure why I was doing that, you showed me the way! Thank you very much!